# get page posts data from of facebook using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing one application using facebook javascript sdk

In this I am trying to get posts of page using bellow code

```
FB.api('/PAGE_ID/posts', { access_token: useraccesstoken}, function (response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

Here I get array of 25 items.Each item contains creation date, message & id.

How can I get other data of page i.e. type of post, link, update time, etc. ?

Comment: By asking for the fields you want. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#fields